# SAP HANA GUID conversion

Tags: guid, hana

in SAP HANA
How can I convert from GUID_C22 data type (16 byte UUID 22) to GUID_X16 (UUID 16 raw).
I'm expeting something like:

```
UUID22: 051Mf5p07jQZifdyH4x5}0  -> UUID16: 0050563C56401D36A348F362444845FC
```

I tried with:
`hextoraw(UUID22)` 
but is not working.

Answer (score 0):

UUID22 and UUID16 are ABAP data types that don't exist on SAP HANA. Therefore there is no built-in conversion function available.
However, you might want to check SCN on this one, as this topic had been discussed there before a couple of times. E.g. [SCN 
Convert GUID_X16 to GUID_C22](http://scn.sap.com/thread/3634015)

Comment: Thank you @Lars for your input. I already checked sdn, some interesting comments but nothing conclusive. I was hoping to do the conversion in HANA DB, not in ABAP. My HANA data types are: VARBINARY(16)RAW  and NVARCHAR(22)STRING. Any idea?

Comment: As mentioned, there is no such conversion function. You may be able to dig out the ABAP code to convert between the two formats and create your own function in SAP HANA.

Answer (score 0):

You must cut in pieces of length 3 the HEX representation of the created UUID and convert each of them into a two character piece of only the digits, the lowercase and uppercase latin letters and the opening and closing curly brace. I created a conversion table  `uuid_conv` with two columns, `hex:CHAR(3)` and `c22:CHAR(2)` for this purpose with content:

```
hex c22
--- ---
000 00
001 01
...
03C 0y
03D 0z
03E 0{
03F 0}
...
FFB }x
FFC }y
FFD }z
FFE }{
FFF }}
```

Use your favourite spreadsheet to generate the necessary content.

Afterwards I joined it something like the following:

```
with uuid as (
    select to_varchar(sysuuid) uuid from dummy
),
y as (
select uuid, substring(uuid,  1, 3) as ta,
         substring(uuid,  4, 3) as tb,
         substring(uuid,  7, 3) as tc,
         substring(uuid, 10, 3) as td,
         substring(uuid, 13, 3) as te,
         substring(uuid, 16, 3) as tf,
         substring(uuid, 19, 3) as tg,
         substring(uuid, 22, 3) as th,
         substring(uuid, 25, 3) as ti,
         substring(uuid, 28, 3) as tj,
         '0'||substring(uuid, 31, 2) as tk
from uuid )
select uuid, ck.c22 || cj.c22 || ci.c22 || ch.c22 || cg.c22 
             || cf.c22 || ce.c22 || cd.c22 || cc.c22 || cb.c22 || ca.c22
from y
inner join uuid_conv ca on (ca.hex = ta)
inner join uuid_conv cb on (cb.hex = tb)
inner join uuid_conv cc on (cc.hex = tc)
inner join uuid_conv cd on (cd.hex = td)
inner join uuid_conv ce on (ce.hex = te)
inner join uuid_conv cf on (cf.hex = tf)
inner join uuid_conv cg on (cg.hex = tg)
inner join uuid_conv ch on (ch.hex = th)
inner join uuid_conv ci on (ci.hex = ti)
inner join uuid_conv cj on (cj.hex = tj)
inner join uuid_conv ck on (ck.hex = tk)
```

A similar construction with SQLSCRIPT functions can be thought of and would be superior.