# How can I join 2 tables with converted UUID field?

Tags: sql, abap, hana

In SAP EWM the material ID is stored in `/SAPAPO/` tables using the data element `/SAPAPO/MATID` which is a CHAR 22. In the other hand, `/SCWM/` tables use the data element `/SCWM/DE_MATID` which is a RAW 16. All the standard code I've seen, uses the class `CL_SYSTEM_UUID` and for instance the method `IF_SYSTEM_UUID_STATIC~CONVERT_UUID_C22` to map a C22 material ID to a X16.

This is preventing me to join tables directly without first selecting, then converting the material ID and finally selecting.

Is there a way to execute a SELECT joining two tables with the different type of ID?

The system is running a HANA database and ABAP 7.50.

The 2 tables I want to join are: `/SAPAPO/MATKEY` and `/SCWM/PVPAKC`

I would like to execute a select similar to this:

```
SELECT FROM /scwm/pvpakc AS pack_spec
  INNER JOIN /sapapo/matkey AS material ON material~matid = pack_spec~matid
  FIELDS pack_spec~pvguid  as ps_guid,
         material~matnr    as material_num
  INTO TABLE @DATA(lt_pack_spec_material).
```

Of course the above join is not possible since the MATID between tables needs to be converted

Comment: https://answers.sap.com/questions/11267190/convert-guidx16-to-guidc22.html

Comment: What ABAP version do you use, and which database system and version, please? Could you provide an example with two tables and GUID columns? Thanks.

Comment: 22 characters GUID encodes 16 bytes by first shifting left by 4 bits and encodes then using 64 characters in the order `0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{}`. Difficult to do it via SQL functions but maybe possible (??)

Comment: @SandraRossi Added version and example

Answer (score 0):

You may try to create database view with the join of these two tables and use it in your selects. [Here on SAPYard](https://sapyard.com/cds-part-17-how-to-overcome-guid-mismatch-linking-problem-in-abap-cds/), having the similar problem, they say that on HANA it goes fine, though giving you a warning

[image]

On my system with Oracle it failed, however, but as you have HANA, you may try.

Also, AMDP functions is your friend, check the tutorial here how to overcome the issue

[ABAP CDS View: Issue faced on join of tables on columns where one column is of RAW data type](http://sapabapcentral.blogspot.com/2018/06/abap-cds-view-issue-faced-on-join-of.html)

Comment: I tested both alternatives but no luck. No errors but no data retrieved from the joined table

Answer (score 0):

If you're on an embedded EWM, you can use table MARA. It has both SCM and APO MATID's in it.

MARA-SCM_MATID_GUID16 (SCM)

MARA-SCM_MATID_GUID22 (APO)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a separate mapping database table and use it for block-wise conversion C22 <-> X16 as is described in these posts ("database approach"):

1. [SAP HANA GUID conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39937102/sap-hana-guid-conversion)
2. [GUID and UUID in SAP HANA](https://www.brandeis.de/en/blog/guid-and-uuid-in-sap-hana) (referring to the first link with extra detail)

Another way is to append a customer field for MATID_X16 to /SAPAPO/MATKEY and to ensure it receives the correct value at product creation ("append approach").

I did some tests (mass selects on /SCWM/AQUA joined to /SAPAPO/MATKEY) comparing both approaches in which the append approach was consistently up to 10 times faster. Still I did't use any SQL scripting, for a start. There is certainly potential for performance improvements in the database approach compared to my tests.